# how to use system environment variables from build in vue?

Tags: docker, vue.js

I want to use the operating system environment variables to builder my project in vue.

I know the `.env` file can be used in root, but for my case, I want vue to get them from the OS, in my case environment variables with docker.

How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

With docker you can add variables in docker-compose.yml

```
   environment:
                MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
                MYSQL_DATABASE: 'DB_DATABASE'
                MYSQL_USER: 'DB_USERNAME'
                MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'DB_PASSWORD'
                MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
```

Comment: I dont want to use the .env file, I want to use the docker env variables when i do the yarn build.

Comment: yarn is a package management tool.. Not folowing what you are trying to achive..

Answer (score 0):

As long as you make the env variables available in node, the node command that serves/build the Vue app will make the variables accessible on `process.env.YOUR_VAR` in any js file of the Vue project.

So now the question is, how to make docker vars available in node, and the answer is here:
https://medium.com/@felipedutratine/pass-environment-variables-from-docker-to-my-nodejs-or-golang-app-a1f2ddec31f5

Basically it summarizes to: `sudo docker run [...] --env-file ./my_env.list [...]`

If you need more info on how to create env vars in docker: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/